# Powershell Wait for Specified Key to Be Pressed Otherwise Timeout

Tags: powershell, timeout

I would like to let the user to enter a specified key (e.g.: $ ) within 5 seconds.
If the user cannot enter the specified key, it will become time out.

```
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

This method allows the user to enter a key, but the console will continue to wait for input, which is not time out. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `[Console]::KeyAvailable` in a while loop and timeout manually.

```
function Read-KeyWithTimeout {
    param([int] $Timeout = 1000)
    end {
        $stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        while (-not [Console]::KeyAvailable) {
            if ($stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds -gt $Timeout) {
                throw 'Timeout hit'
            }

            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
        }

        $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown')
    }
}
```

When `[Console]::KeyAvailable` returns true there is input in the buffer waiting to be read.

**Note:** On Unix this *will still echo the input* because of how `System.Console` is implemented.

Comment: The code works! May I ask what is the purpose of this line: Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50 ?

Comment: @DanEng Just good practice.  All of the code within runs virtually instantly, if you don't sleep it will repeatedly run the loop as fast as it can consuming way more resources than it needs to.  You can lower or raise the ms count depending on your needs but I would highly recommend you don't remove it.